# Extending adapter pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, adapter

I have an interface **IA**. Adapter  **B** implements that interface. **IZ** is an interface which is implemented by  **X**, **Y** and **Z** classes. IA is an interface with which my application talks with to communicate with X , Y and Z using adapter **B**. B contains an instance of IZ (Adapter pattern). Now from adapter B, I want to access functionality which is unique to X, but since in adapter it is bound to interface IZ, how can I access this functionality in a **clean** way ? Also the instance of IZ in adapter B is decided at runtime based on some manual activity of user. Is there any way I can use dependency injection to instantiate the instance of IZ in adapter B (I want to avoid using *new* operator)?
IA 
|
B (has an instance of IZ)

IZ 
/ | \ 
X Y Z

EDIT : There are high chances that X' , Y' , Z' can come into picture...all with same interface IZ but Y' might have one method (might not be same as X) that is required to be accessed from B. Both the unique methods of Y' and X will adapt to some common method M in interface IA

I don't have control over X, Y and Z or X', Y', Z' other than they can implement IZ interface. But I have control over IA and B. I used adapter pattern essentially so that new classes can adapt to my interface IA

Comment: Well what you expect to happen if adapter B were created with an instance of Y or Z, instead of X?

Comment: It sounds like you should put more members on IZ then - make Y and Z implement those members by returning the "constant stuff" and make X do whatever it's normally meant to.

Comment: There are high chances that  X' , Y' , Z' can come into picture...all with same interface but Y' might have one method (might not be same as X) that is required to be accessed from B. Both the unique methods of Y' and X will adapt to some common method M in interface IA

Comment: It's going to be very hard for anyone to give a useful answer with the requirements coming in dribs and drabs like this. I suggest you think about everything you can express about the question, and edit it.

Comment: I have edited the question, note that I don't have control over X, Y and Z or X', Y',  Z' other than they can implement IZ interface. But I have control over IA and B. I used adapter pattern essentially so that new classes can adapt to my interface IA

Comment: Have a look here as well http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your class `B` wants to access part of `X`'s public interface that isn't exposed through `IZ`, then it is no longer just an adapter for the `IZ` interface.

It sounds to me like you need separate adapters for the different *types* if they aren't being accessed through a common interface. Since it sounds from your description that there's likely to be a lot of common functionality, you could use inheritance between the adapters to avoid code duplication.

You probably want a factory for creating adapters based upon the type of the object being adapted. A factory could also be used to instantiate the instance of `X`, `Y` *&c*, and the necessary adapter for it, based upon user activity as required.